# Как вставить переменные в строку?

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно сдеать так:

`cout << "My name is {name}. I am {age}";`, где name и age - изменяемые переменные.

В C# перед кавычками нужно добавить $, в Python - f.

А как это активировать в C++?

Comment: Вот так: cout << "My name is " << name <<". I am "<< age;

Answer (score 6):

В С++20 можно делать похожим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
 
int main()
{
    auto const & name{"Frob"};
    auto const age{42};
    ::std::cout << ::std::format("My name is {}. I am {}", name, age);
}
```

Ну а пока можно использовать аналогичные варианты из сторонних библиотек, тот же {fmt} или folly.

Answer (score 5):

В стандартной библиотеке с++ такая возможность внедрена только в 20-ом стандарте - функция `std::format`. Так как это еще очень новый и слабо поддерживаемый стандарт, то в вашем случае есть два варианта:

1. использовать сишную функцию `printf` (или `sprintf` если вам нужно получить в результате строку а не вывод)
2. использовать `boost::format` - очень хорошая либа как раз для этих целей